# Program to time sort algorithms keeps crashing

Tags: c, sorting, clock, timing, time.h

I have some code that was meant to time sort algorithms (for school) but it keeps crashing whenever array size is bigger than just 20k.

This is the main file I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "sorting.h"

#define ARG_COUNT 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    if (argc != ARG_COUNT + 1) {
        printf("Too few or too many arguments passed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (atoi(argv[1]) < 10000) {
        printf("Array lenght should be at least 10 000.");
        exit(2);
    }

    int arr_lenght = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(time(0));

    int *arr1 = (int *)calloc(arr_lenght, arr_lenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_lenght; i++) {
        arr1[i] = rand() % 20;
    }

    int *arr2 = (int *)calloc(arr_lenght, arr_lenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_lenght; i++) {
        arr2[i] = rand() % 20;
    }

    //INSERTION SORT TIMER
    int ticks_start = clock();
    insertion_sort(arr1, arr_lenght);
    int ticks_finish = clock();

    float net_ticks = ticks_finish - ticks_start;
    printf("insertion sort time:");
    printf("%fl\n", (double)net_ticks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    
    //MERGE SORT TIMER
    ticks_start = clock();
    merge_sort(arr2, 0, arr_lenght - 1);
    ticks_finish = clock();

    net_ticks = ticks_finish - ticks_start;
    printf("merge sort time:");
    printf("%fl\n", (double)net_ticks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //free
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);

    return 0;
}
```

The `main` function is meant to accept the array size as a command line argument and fill 2 arrays of that size with pseudo random values, then sort one with merge sort and one with insertion sort and compare the times.

Comment: There is nothing in your posted code that would account for a crash (i.e. segfault). Please edit your question and post the remaining code. Specifically, the code for `insertion_sort` and `merge_sort` and any functions they call. We should be able to download the code, compile/build it, and run it [on our systems if we so choose]. Have you built the code with `-g` to get debug symbols and run it under `gdb`?

Comment: You allocate too much. `calloc` takes the number of items and the size of one item, so `calloc(N, sizeof(*p))` allocates as much as `malloc(N * sizeof(*p))`. In effect, you ask for `N * N * sizeof(int)` bytes, which may be too much. (And the system should tell you so by returning a `NULL` pointer.)

Comment: And this sort of thing is among the reasons why you should always check the error indicators that may be raised by your function calls -- often, but not always, via their return values -- and take appropriate action.  Cultivate the habit now, while you're still learning, and it will serve you well when the stakes are higher than the grade on one homework assignment.

Comment: Nitpick: The pseudo random values in the two arrays will not be the same. This may affect the results. Better to `memcpy()` the first array to the second so both sort operations work with the same data in the same original sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are allocating an excess of memory.

`calloc(length, length * sizeof (int))` allocates `length * length * sizeof (int)` bytes. You are likely confusing this with the typical `malloc` pattern of `malloc(length * sizeof (int))`.

Assuming a 4-byte `int` and a length of 20000, each allocation takes 1.6GB of memory.

In the event that `calloc` fails to allocate memory, it will return `NULL`. Some implementations (e.g., [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html)) will set `errno` to `ENOMEM` when this happens.

You should always test the return value of library functions that can fail.

```
int *arr1 = calloc(length, sizeof *arr1);

if (!arr1) {
    perror("calloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Probably the correct answer but.... allocating 1.6G should not be a problem on modern systems so.... well, don't know but UV anyway

Comment: @SupportUkraine: there are 2 allocations. If the program is compiled in 32-bits allocating 3.2 GB in user land may well fail.

Comment: @chqrlie 32 bits.... are they still around ;-)

Comment: @SupportUkraine "32 bits.... are they still around " --> most processors in 2022 are embedded ones - _billions_ per year.  Most are 32-bit _or_ smaller.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Clarified the answer a bit. Thanks.